# Kollo Skewness - Calculation and meaning

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I would like to calculate the Kollo Skewness which is defined [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X08000626) in Definition 2.

$b(x) = E\left [ \sum (Y_{i}Y_{j})Y \right ]$
where $Y = \Sigma ^{-1/2} (X-\mu)$ with $E[X] = \mu$ and $\Sigma$ is the dispersion matrix (Covariance Matrix).

I am strugling to grasp the intuition behind the Kollo Skewness. A good first step would be understanding the thinking behind $Y$. What is the effect of premultiplying with the inverse of the cholesky decomposition of the Covariance Matrix?

I have also written a Matlab function to calculate the sample Kollo Skewness.
$\widehat{b(X)} = \frac{1}{n}1_{pxp}\star\sum_{n}^{i=1}(y_{i}y_{i}'\otimes y_{i})$

```
function [ B ] = KolloSkew( X )
%sample estimate for Kollo Skewness
%   
%   Calculation according to Def. 3 Kollo (2008)
%
%   Input:
%   X: mxn of sample data
%   
%   Output:
%   B: Kollo Skewness Vector

[m, n] = size(X);
S = cov(X);

%%  Y
Y = zeros(size(X,2));
for j=1:n
    % yi = S^(-1/2)*(xi-x.mean)
    Y(:,j) = (chol(S)')^(-1)*(X(1,:)'-mean(X(:,1)));
end

%% B = 1/n 1pxp star sum
temp1 = 1/m * ones(n); %temp1: 1/n 1pxp
temp2 = zeros(4,2); %temp2: sum yi*yi' kron yi*yi'
for j=1:n
    temp2 = temp2 + kron(Y(:,j)*Y(:,j)',Y(:,j)); 
end


B = star(temp1, temp2);

end

%% star product
function [ starprod ] = star( A, B )
% star product according to Def. 1 Kollo
r = size(B,1) / size(A,1);
s = size(B,2) / size(A,2);

n = size(A,2);
m = size(A,1);

temp3 = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:m
   for j=1:n
       temp3 = temp3 + A(i,j) * B(1+(i-1)*r:i*r, 1+(j-1)*s:j*s);
   end 
end

starprod = temp3;
end
```

Comment: Nobody answers you because, in the "definition of Kollow (or Kollo ???) Skewness", it is impossible to understand what is all this about: for example, it refers to a certain random variable $Y$ which is defined elsewhere. Moreover, internet searches do not bring back anything with the keyword "Kollow"; It is not serious. I propose to close this question.

Comment: It is Kollo, not Kollow ; have a look at (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X08000626)

Comment: @JeanMarie I have revised my question an would appriciate if you would consider removing the on hold.

Comment: I have done it.